# How do I tell python where to find Windows DLL files when using ubuntu (WSL)?

Tags: python, dll, libraries, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running `64-bit Windows` with `Python version 3.6.9` on the `ubuntu/WSL shell`. My goal is to be able to write my own application using these `.dll files` provided by `Thorlabs` for a piece of lab equipment. Their documentation makes it sound pretty simple `(see the [screenshot][1]): just copy over the dll file to your python project folder`.

However, when I try to write a simple test

```
from ctypes import *

MC2000BLib = cdll.LoadLibrary("MC2000CommandLibWin32.dll")
```

the error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    MC2000BLib = cdll.LoadLibrary("MC2000CommandLibWin32.dll")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: MC2000CommandLibWin32.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What I've tried so far:

````
 - Changed the filename to ```MC2000CommandLibx64.dll``` as they suggested for 64-bit systems but I got the exact same error.
 - Ran an ```os.environ``` output from the python program and saw that ```'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/usr/local/lib'``` and I guess ubuntu looks to ```/usr/lib/``` for its .so files.
 - ```export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Thorlabs/MC2000B/``` and then ```sudo ldconfig```. Same result.
````

So the question is where do I have to put these `dll files` in order for my program to recognize them and use them?

Comment: WSL is a Linux implementation and a Python you are using there is a Python running on Linux. I'd be really surprised if you could load a DLL in that environment. You can probably load Shared Object (*.so) files well. If you want to use those DLLs you will probably have to use a Windows implementation on Python, not WSL one.

Answer (score 0):

Their documentation is for Windows, but you are using Linux (inside Windows, but that's irrelevant), not Windows!

If you use Python in WSL, you cannot load a DLL. WSL is Linux - DLL files are for Windows.

You'll have to use the Windows version of Python instead (which you could still *call* from WSL if you wanted to, using `python.exe` instead of `python`), or check if there are Linux versions of those library files (typically `.so` files then).

(Also: It won't work here anyway, but in any case the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` path format would be wrong too - `C:/something` is a Windows path (with a forward slash instead of a backslash though), but you are using Linux, so the right path would have been `/mnt/c/something`, since WSL mounts Windows' drives as `/mnt/c` etc.)

Comment: I see. Unfortunately they do not provide a .so file for Linux so I tried calling python.exe in WSL and got `command not found`. Do I need to link it somewhere?

Comment: Make sure it's in your `PATH`. And maybe it's `python3.exe`.